# Remove single quotations & split parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am new to Python and am playing around with data sets. I need help trying to:
1.Remove the single quotations for the dates within the parentheses
2.Split the parenthesis into an array (31312 x 4)

Code:
    import csv
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

```
text_file = open("Claims1.txt", "r")
dfl = DataFrameList = list(text_file)
text_file.close()


dfl_string = "\n".join(str(e) for e in dfl)
dfl_split = dfl_string.replace('),', ')//').split('//')


my_df = pd.DataFrame(dfl_split)
#Output into CSV file
my_df.to_csv('output.csv')



Current Result:
     0
0   (1,'2000-01-04',328647,5000)
1   (2,'2000-01-09',465858,5000)
2   (3,'2000-01-09',378115,5000)
3   (4,'2000-01-14',121895,5000)
4   (5,'2000-01-16',325172,5000)
5   (6,'2000-01-16',156062,5000)
6   (7,'2000-01-17',472142,5000)
...............................
31312 (31312, '2004-05-30',340406, 5000)

Desired Result:
    0       1         2      3
0   1  2000-01-04  328647  5000
1   2  2000-01-09  465858  5000
2   3  2000-01-09  378115  5000
3   4  2000-01-14  121895  5000
4   5  2000-01-16  325172  5000
5   6  2000-01-16  156062  5000
6   7  2000-01-17  472142  5000
..............................
31312 31312 '2004-05-30'340406 5000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you might be getting a `ValueError` is probably because each of your inputs are read in as a `string`. Hence you get a *string of lists* instead of *list of lists*.

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
y = [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in dfl_split]
df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=[0, 1, 2, 3])
print(df)
```

This will work.

Comment: Fair play! Worked perfectly :) yeah overlooked the initial part where i had joined it up as a string earlier on for dfl_string

Comment: @DerrickChua please accept the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your data in a dataframe, you can split into columns using `pd.Series.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[(1,'2000-01-04',328647,5000),
                      (2,'2000-01-09',465858,5000),
                      (3,'2000-01-09',378115,5000),
                      (4,'2000-01-14',121895,5000),
                      (5,'2000-01-16',325172,5000),
                      (6,'2000-01-16',156062,5000),
                      (7,'2000-01-17',472142,5000)]})

df[[0, 1, 2, 3]] = df[0].apply(pd.Series)

#    0           1       2     3
# 0  1  2000-01-04  328647  5000
# 1  2  2000-01-09  465858  5000
# 2  3  2000-01-09  378115  5000
# 3  4  2000-01-14  121895  5000
# 4  5  2000-01-16  325172  5000
# 5  6  2000-01-16  156062  5000
# 6  7  2000-01-17  472142  5000
```

Comment: I got a "ValueError('Columns must be same length as key')". Would you have a way to split the parentheses? The DataFrame function didnt split it

Answer (score 2):

Data from jpp, should be fast

```
pd.DataFrame(df[0].tolist())
Out[779]: 
   0           1       2     3
0  1  2000-01-04  328647  5000
1  2  2000-01-09  465858  5000
2  3  2000-01-09  378115  5000
3  4  2000-01-14  121895  5000
4  5  2000-01-16  325172  5000
5  6  2000-01-16  156062  5000
6  7  2000-01-17  472142  5000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your result to a dataframe like this (Note `data` here is your current result):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [(1,'2000-01-04',328647,5000),
        (2,'2000-01-09',465858,5000),
        (3,'2000-01-09',378115,5000),
        (4,'2000-01-14',121895,5000),
        (5,'2000-01-16',325172,5000),
        (6,'2000-01-16',156062,5000),
        (7,'2000-01-17',472142,5000)]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[0, 1, 2, 3])
print(df)

#   0          1      2    3 
# 0 1 2000-01-04 328647 5000 
# 1 2 2000-01-09 465858 5000 
# 2 3 2000-01-09 378115 5000 
# 3 4 2000-01-14 121895 5000 
# 4 5 2000-01-16 325172 5000 
# 5 6 2000-01-16 156062 5000 
# 6 7 2000-01-17 472142 5000
```

Comment: I think I'm still short of splitting the parentheses as the array shape is still different. I modified my initial code to my_df = pd.DataFrame(dfl_split) but still get a "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 31312), indices imply (4, 31312)"